# Sails Server Through Error on Starting

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am new in sails.
When i run command sails lift to start the server its show error.
I don't understand what it is?

```
    error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
    error: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "jst:dev" (jst) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'maxmin' 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
    error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching            for changes in assets)
    error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

    error: Troubleshooting tips:
    error: 
    error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm     install` if you're not sure.
    error: 
    error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
    error: 
    error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
    error:      e.g., `/Users/tayyabzahid/Developer/Scitech/Node/Sails/activityOverlord/.tmp` ?
    error: 
    error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
    error:      sudo chown -R 501     /Users/tayyabzahid/Developer/Scitech/Node/Sails/activityOverlord/.tmp
```

What can it do to solve it...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It already told you how to troubleshoot. What are the results of the listed steps?

Comment: i already troubleshoot it. but same error appear

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I have tried npm installing maxmin but no change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624877/sails-js-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall/use different version for 'grunt-contrib-jst' module. Worked for me

Comment: this could have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error on a fresh install.
Removing all modules and reinstalling them to be sure they are up to date solved the problem for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```