# Sails Js permissions

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

I got a sailsjs app on a debian server. My only user is root, I installed everything in root (npm install, npm install sails -g, npm install pm2 -g). When I try to deploy it with my root user (sails lift --prod), I got permissions errors :

```
Grunt :: Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
Grunt :: Cleaning .tmp/public...
Grunt :: Warning: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory. 
** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp/public...Warning: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I checked permissions for every folder, they are all owned by root.

Anyone got that problem ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like, you updated your Node.Try to delete .tmp folder
Also edit tasks/config/clean.js:

```
  grunt.config.set('clean', {
    options: { force: true },
    dev: ['.tmp/public/**'],
    build: ['www']
  });
```

Comment: Great answer!! options: { force: true } Fixed my issue. Tried other things for hours...

Answer (score 1):

You can add 

`options: { force: true }`

option to Grunt task
Also, can you provide full Gruntfile?